# h1 elements above div using z-index

Tags: header, z-index

I tried to place an **h1** element above a **div** element using the css property **z-index**, but it's not working!

Here's my html:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="headerblock">
</div>
<h1>This is my header text</h1>
</div>
```

The #headerblock has a black surface including some transparency.
I want the h1 to be appearing above the #headerblock. As I mentioned the z-index property isn't working. Does someone have a solution for this? Or at least a reason why it's not working?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us any of your CSS? This would a great thing to have in a jsfiddle

Comment: This is weird. Using jsfiddle it's working as I want it to

Comment: No sorry it's not working, i'll post the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9cthv8r/

Answer (score 9):

Gotta have a `position` on the h1.

```css
h1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 500;
}

#header{
 background-image: url(img/head.jpg);
 background-size: 100%;
 height: 520px;
 width: 100%;
 top:49px;
 position: absolute;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
}

#headerblock{
 background-color:#444444;
 opacity:0.7;
 filter:alpha(opacity=70);
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headerblock"></div>
  <h1 style="color:white">This is my header text</h1>
</div>
```